# How can i connect my Nextcloud with my Samba Server?

Tags: active-directory, samba, nextcloud

How can I connect my Nextcloud with my Samba 4 Server?
Do I need to add something to my Samba 4 Server?
I want that when I create a user in the Active Directory of the Samba 4 Server and add it to the VPN Group that it automatically creates a Nextcloud user with the same credentials and syncs if something changes.

What do I need to get this to work?

I already tried to connect the Nextcloud via LDAP, but it does not work out of the box.

Comment: I did. In not long enough here to uplike tho. Thanks for the reminder I did miss the entire message. Stay healthy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   You will need PHP-LDAP module for authenticating LDAP users in Nextcloud and sync them from the LDAP application. Also, a correctly configured SELinux setup is needed for the LDAP backend to work.

•   Then enable the ‘LDAP user and group backend’ app on the apps page in Nextcloud. Once that has been done, switch to the admin page for configuring the LDAP server details. On the admin page, in the servers tab, configure the LDAP server details correctly like the authentication account details on the LDAP server, base DN and the port number through the domain details which will be fetched.

•   Then, on the users tab, configure the users who have access to nextcloud and who can login to the nextcloud server after which configure the login attributes for which the users from the LDAP will be providing the requisite details and synced.
Once, this is configured, your nextcloud server is ready to work with Samba LDAP server but if you want any specific custom settings to be set, you can do that through the advanced settings option provided like connection settings, directory settings, special attributes, expert settings and other details.

Please find the below links for more detailed information on steps for integrating nextcloud with samba ldap features and syncing users: -

[Nextcloud with Samba via LDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187323/nextcloud-with-samba-via-ldap)

https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration_user/user_auth_ldap.html